# How do you retrieve your wallet balance with HWI?

Tags: balance, hwi

How do you retrieve your wallet balance with HWI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

HWI is stateless - it has no way to query the blockchain and does not store any information about your  hardware wallets, so it is unable to know or retrieve your hardware wallet's balance. Furthermore, hardware wallets are essentially offline devices and also have no way to know or retrieve its balance.

This is why a software wallet must be used with a hardware wallet as the software wallet will watch your hardware wallet's addresses, learn about its UTXOs, and be able to create transactions.